# C# : Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to view/open a document but I am getting this error. Please help.

This is my code:

```cs
    byte[] fileText = (byte[])dataTable.Rows[0]["fileContent"];  //Error occurs here
```

Comment: Depending on your specific scenario, you may want to make sure the database does have the data (making the database column NOT NULL)

Comment: [DataRow.IsNull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.isnull?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @Cleptus ''if(dataTable.Rows[0] != DBNull.Value)'' this returns an error opeartor cannot be applied